# Как вывести записи понедельника?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
InvoiceNo   StockCode   Description Quantity    UnitPrice   CustomerID  Country
InvoiceDate                         
2010-12-07 13:01:00 537604  84991   60 TEATIME FAIRY CAKE CASES 24  0.55    13488.0 United Kingdom
2010-12-07 13:01:00 537604  21845   DAIRY MAID STRIPE MUG   12  2.95    13488.0 United Kingdom
2010-12-07 13:01:00 537604  21534   DAIRY MAID LARGE MILK JUG   3   4.95    13488.0 United Kingdom
2010-12-07 13:01:00 537604  21527   RED RETROSPOT TRADITIONAL TEAPOT    2   7.95    13488.0 United Kingdom
2010-12-07 13:01:00 537604  21528   DAIRY MAID TRADITIONAL TEAPOT
```

Найдите количество клиентов, которые оформляли заказ в понедельники. Для этого:

сделайте подвыборку, соответствующую условию "в понедельник", используйте метод datetime индекса weekday_name
посчитайте кол-во уникальных ID клиентов

Я делаю:

```
data[(data.index.weekday_name == '0')].head
```

Выводит:

> Empty DataFrame

Comment: Пожалуйста, найдите способ копировать данные в вопрос текстом, а не картинкой. Это повысит качество вопроса, и следовательно, повысит вероятность скорейшего ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data[(data.index.weekday_name == 'Monday')]
```

или

```
data[(data.index.weekday == 0)]
```

---

чтобы посчитать число уникальных клиентов, которые оформляли заказ в понедельники:

```
uniq_cust_no = data.loc[(data.index.weekday == 0), "CustomerID"].nunique()
```